# Teens on an island, forced to kill eachother, collars prevents co-operation

Tags: horror

I must admit I'm on shaking ground here, because I haven't seen it, I've just heard this movie menioned once (about five years ago?) - or at least I think it was a movie, but since I think it's based on a book, it may be the book I've heared mentioned.  In retrospect, it may have been early talks about "The Hunger Games" - but I think not.

Some (young?) teens have been abudcted and placed on an island (or somewhere else remote and isolated).  (I assume) Only one of them will be allowed to leave, so they'll have to fight and kill eachoter.  To prevent them from co-operating - or hatching a plan to escape - they've all been collared with something aikin to shock-collars that will shock them (and possibly kill them) if they spend too much time in proximity to eachother.

I believe it's somewhat "Saw"-like...